# How create data to two store in indexedDB in onupgradeneeded

Tags: indexeddb

Can I ask how i can create data in two store(table) in indexedDb in time when store are created?

In this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vavbhbcs/5/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

function open() {
  indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

    var version = 1;
    var request = indexedDB.open("appaa", version);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;

        e.target.transaction.onerror = indexedDB.onerror;

        if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("tab1")) {
            db.deleteObjectStore("tab1");
        }

        var storeColl = db.createObjectStore("tab1", {
            keyPath: "id", autoIncrement : true
        });
        storeColl.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: true });
        storeColl.createIndex("description", "description", { unique: false });

        storeColl.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            var collObjectStore = db.transaction("tab1", "readwrite").objectStore("tab1");
            collObjectStore.add({name: "a", description: "b"});
            collObjectStore.add({name: "c", description: "d"});                
        };


      if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("tab2")) {
            db.deleteObjectStore("tab2");
        }

        var storeColl2 = db.createObjectStore("tab2", {
            keyPath: "id", autoIncrement : true
        });
        storeColl2.createIndex("name2", "name2", { unique: true });
        storeColl2.createIndex("description2", "description2", { unique: false });

        storeColl2.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            var collObjectStore2 = db.transaction("tab2", "readwrite").objectStore("tab2");
            collObjectStore2.add({name: "a2", description: "b2"});
            collObjectStore2.add({name: "c2", description: "d2"});                
        };



    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;

    };

    request.onerror = function(){

    };


  };

open();

});
```

If i create only one store, data are added. But If i create two store, data are created only in second store.

Answer (score 2):

Although `storeColl` references two different object stores, both calls to `storeColl.transaction` return the same transaction object - the "versionchange" transaction automatically created as part of the upgrade process. So when your code does:

```
storeColl.transaction.oncomplete = ...;

...

storeColl.transaction.oncomplete = ...;
```

The second assignment to `oncomplete` overwrites the first, and only the last handler assigned to `oncomplete` runs.

A simple fix would be to use `storeColl.transaction.addEventListener('complete', ...);` instead, since you can add multiple event listeners that way.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wait for createObjectStore to complete. You can immediately store data using the event.target.transaction. This is not a recommended practice. However, here is an example:

```
function onUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  // ...

  // Create the object stores
  var db = event.target.result;
  var tab1Create = db.createObjectStore("tab1", {
    keyPath: "id", autoIncrement : true
  });

  var tab2Create = db.createObjectStore("tab2", {
    keyPath: "id", autoIncrement : true
  });

  // ...

  // Time to add some data:
  // Get a reference to the current transaction. The transaction 
  // type is 'versionchange', which allows for 'readwrite' operations
  var transaction = event.target.transaction;

  // Access the object stores using the transaction and add objects
  var tab1 = transaction.objectStore('tab1');
  tab1.add({name: "a", description: "b"});
  tab1.add({name: "c", description: "d"});
  var tab2 = transaction.objectStore('tab2');
  tab2.add({name: "a2", description: "b2"});
  tab2.add({name: "c2", description: "d2"});
}
```

Comment: Yea, it works, if don't mind that i don't wait for complete?

Comment: You do not need to wait for createObjectStore to complete when inside the onupgradeneeded function, because the function is synchronous (it starts executing immediately and later statements wait to start until it finishes).